# Print all the instances of a matching pattern in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I've been trying to print all the instances of a matching pattern from file.

**Input file:**

```
{"id":"prod123","a":1.3,"c":"xyz","q":2}, 
{"id":"prod456","a":1.3,"c":"xyz","q":1}]}
{"id":"prod789","a":1.3,"currency":"xyz","q":2}, 
{"id":"prod101112","a":1.3,"c":"xyz","q":1}]}
```

I'd want to print everything between `"id":"` and `",`.

**Expected output:**

```
prod123
prod456
prod789
prod101112
```

I'm using the command

```
grep -Eo 'id\"\:\"[^"]+"\"\,*' | grep -Eo '^[^"]+'
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do you have `jq` installed?

Comment: Your output seems to be a `grep` or whatever on a JSON file. You might be interested in using `jq` on your full file. But for this, we should need to see how this thing looks like.

Comment: Use *some* JSON parser, whether it be `jq` or a module in your language of choice. *Don't* use line-oriented tools like `grep` or `awk` to try to parse JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What went wrong is the place of the comma in the first `grep`:

```
grep -Eo 'id.\:.[^"]+"\,"' inputfile
```

You need to do something extra for getting the desired substring.

```
grep -Eo 'id.\:.[^"]+"\,"' inputfile | cut -d: -f2 | grep -Eo '[^",]+'
```

I used `cut`, that would be easy for your example input.

```
cut -d'"' -f4 < inputfile
```

You have alternatives, like using `jq`, or

```
sed -r 's/\{"id":"([^"]*).*/\1/' inputfile
```

or using awk (solution now like `cut` but can be changed easy)

```
awk -F'"' '{print $4}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped and I got the desired result.